# How can I improve the questions that make me be forbidden to ask new questions?

Tags: support, specific-question, post-ban

I've been banned from asking questions.

I have 2 questions that were voted negatively:

- [ReferenceError: ajax is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43576699/referenceerror-ajax-is-not-defined)
- [Update an array in a Postgres table using a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51935520/update-a-array-in-postgre-table-using-a-function)

The first question can not be changed because it was closed because it was off-topic.

The second question I tried to correct, but I did not succeed in getting it improved.

Can someone with more knowledge take a look at my second question, and try to point out what I can improve for it to be reviewed positively?

What should I do with the first question that was answered, and corrected my problem at the time, but since it was outside the site's topic was voted negatively?

Comment: You can edit closed & even deleted posts.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first thing that I notice in both your questions is that they're *long*.

The first question has an immense wall of code, that you could've stripped down yourself before posting it on Stack Overflow. Some debugging would have led to that code narrowed down to only the necessary part (the `window.onload` ajax call). This is part of the [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirements, namely the *Minimal* part.

The second question I'm not too sure of (SQL is not my area of expertise), but I feel like there's also some unnecessary information in there. The question starts off very broad (how do I implement X?) which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow, after which you start to explain that you have this code which is not working, which *is* on-topic. You should probably cut out the first part, and have a clear problem statement: I have *this* code, I want it do this *this*, but instead it does *this*.

Comment: Hi @Jesse de Bruijne,  I tried to improve the second question using your information, can you check if something has improved, or do I need to give some more improvements to the question?

Comment: @JoseMarques I have edited your question with some spelling corrections and removed some unnecessary parts, like the "Hi" at the start or the "Thank you" at the bottom. These are generally not necessary in a question and are considered noise. I have also upvoted the question, because it looks a lot better now.

Comment: Thanks now I understand that I can not put all the code and I must be more careful to put so much information unnecessary for my problem even if I think it can help others.

Comment: @JoseMarques, the other people you have to be *most* concerned with helping are those whom you hope will answer your questions, and this answer describes ways to do that.  As it turns out, that tends to be helpful to the more general audience, too.  All the cool but unnecessary (to the question) code you provided?  People who might be interested in that code are unlikely to run across the question in the first place.

Comment: @JoseMarques another benefit of simplifying your code to the MCVE is that it often helps clarify the problem for yourself, potentially enabling you to discover the  fix yourself before asking the question.

Comment: "how do I implement X [...] which is not on-topic for Stack Overflow" SO is filled with this type of question. The most upvoted answers on the site are exactly this type of question. This is the stuff people type into Google and then come here to learn about. It is the 'fix my code' questions that should be off-topic, those don't help anybody but the asker.

Comment: @CrisLuengo The reason you might find highly upvoted "how do I implement X?" questions is because they're from ten years back, when the rules were different. Just take a look at the HTML tag, one in ten questions are something along the lines of "How do I make this in HTML and Javascript?" and they all get closed. ([First question in the HTML tag when I wrote this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52216723/how-to-generate-css3-shapes)) If I look at the Hot questions in SO right now, all of them have some code, and then ask a question about said code.

Comment: I know what the current rules are, I think they’re wrong.

Comment: @CrisLuengo As do we all, but the system is the system, and there is nothing even close to being this useful, so the rules are working to some degree.

Comment: @BillK: Every time I Google for something related to Git or CMake or whatever, I end up on an SO page that is either closed or should be closed according to current standards. It's always questions with tons of votes, and they're the questions that make SO useful. Forcing people to add code to a question that doesn't need it is pointless. Most of the questions that go unchallenged today because they have code are "what's wrong with my code, I don't know how to debug" type questions, which I know nobody will ever hit git a Google search. Useful? No!

Comment: @CrisLuengo I agree, the good, interesting questions are closed while the "Please do my homework" are encouraged and have 10 answers quickly because they are so easy to answer.  Still, you can at least still see the closed questions--the fact that they still come up even after the question is closed is amazingly helpful.  I do what I can, vote up questions as others try to close them, etc, but it's a loosing battle.  They are going to need a "This question has been closed because it is interesting" tag soon.